# The correct way to set a function generic and overload it with different arguments within a package

Tags: r, package, generic-programming, r-s4

Let's assume that I want to define the function `rankMatrix` from the `Matrix` package for my own S4 class objects. Doing this in a running R session seems to be straightforward:

```
library(devtools); library(roxygen2); library(Matrix)

########################################################
################ code used in the package ##############

#' testclass
#' 
#' @import Matrix
#' @import methods
#' @export
setClass("MatrixReloaded", slots = list(sl = "Matrix", sr = "Matrix"))

#' constructor of MatrixReloaded
#' @export
MatrixReloaded <- function(x, y) new("MatrixReloaded", sl = x, sr = y)

# make rankMatrix generic
setGeneric("rankMatrix", Matrix::rankMatrix)

# and define new method for class MatrixReloaded
setMethod("rankMatrix", signature(x = "MatrixReloaded"), 
          function(x, tol) 
           rankMatrix(x = x@sl, tol = tol) + 
            rankMatrix(x = x@sr, tol = tol)
          )

########################################################
########################################################

# Create a MatrixReloaded object
(newobj <- MatrixReloaded(Diagonal(1), Matrix(1:10, ncol=2)))

#### and compare results

# sum the ranks individually -- works as rankMatrix
# can handle objects of class Matrix per default
rankMatrix(newobj@sl) + rankMatrix(newobj@sr)
rankMatrix(newobj) # call rankMatrix on the actual MatrixReloaded object
```

This seems to work well... In particular, `methods("rankMatrix")` yields

```
rankMatrix,ANY-method rankMatrix,MatrixReloaded-method
```

**The actual problem**

If I build a package containing the class, the constructor as well as including the lines regarding `rankMatrix` and then start a new R session, install as well as load the [package](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11635972/myTempPack_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz.html), `methods("rankMatrix")` gives the same result, however `rankMatrix(newobj)` fails due to the fact, that the function is not called for the correct class.

- What did I do wrong?
- Do the arguments have to exactly match those of the generic default function?
- If yes, is there a way to ignore arguments of the default function (e.g. `sval` in `rankMatrix` as I don't want R to run the `svd` on the `MatrixReloaded` object)?

Comment: I don't think that `newobj@sl` will have the proper structure to be of class MatrixReloaded. It's only going to be a Matrix, and rankMatrix has no method for an item with that signature.

Comment: @42- : Thanks for your comment. The penultimate line is just a check, whether the function `rankMatrix` on the `MatrixReloaded` object `newobj` in the last line does the correct thing -- namely sum the ranks of both single matrices. And `rankMatrix` (as part of the `Matrix` package) is written in a way, that it can also be used with `Matrix` objects, though there is no explicit method for this class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my first problem is quite simple: I did forget to `@export` the new generic method, as e.g. stated [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html)